# how can use open methode in database in newactivity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio-2.0

```
public class ContentView1 extends ActionBarActivity {

private ListView Content1;
private List<HashMap<String,Object>> books_List;
private  dbHandler db;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_content_view1);

    getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
    Content1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.BtnListView);

    db=new dbHandler(getBaseContext());
    db.close();
    db.open();
```

When wright open database method for  new activity i see error in open
how can fix it?

Please guide me

Comment: Could you please post dbHandler class contents?

Answer (score 0):

you have to 1st open database and then you can close that.

```
db.open();
//your databa

db.close();
```